# When I use flutter http library with headers authorization token, its shows 500, in console. but in postman all okay

Tags: flutter, http, header, authorization, token

Here is my code, I also tried using retrofit but I failed and it shows 500 and "message": "Undefined index: token".  but in postman, it shows 200. how can it be possible?

Also tried
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',

```
Future getCertificateList() async {
  final url = Uri.parse(
      'https://portal-api.jomakhata.com/api/getCertificateList');
  final response = await http.get(url,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjI4OTksImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vcG9ydGFsLWFwaS5qb21ha2hhdGEuY29tL2FwaS9hdXRoL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNjI4NjE0MDcyLCJleHAiOjE2Mjg3MDA0NzIsIm5iZiI6MTYyODYxNDA3MiwianRpIjoiRnRjaGllbTFFdVlsYXZidyJ9.O24U0XGFiZdfXRGUP5xYD82-LisSbMsCtVZnuG6iTiY',
      },
  );
  print(response.statusCode);
  print(response.body);
  return response.body;
}
```

[In my console it's print 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I52ir.png)
[this is postman request image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTUXT.png)

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
Future getCertificateList() async { 
 final uri = Uri.https('https://portal-api.jomakhata.com','/api/getCertificateList');
    final response = await http.get(uri, headers: {
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
          'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjI4OTksImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vcG9ydGFsLWFwaS5qb21ha2hhdGEuY29tL2FwaS9hdXRoL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNjI4NjE0MDcyLCJleHAiOjE2Mjg3MDA0NzIsIm5iZiI6MTYyODYxNDA3MiwianRpIjoiRnRjaGllbTFFdVlsYXZidyJ9.O24U0XGFiZdfXRGUP5xYD82-LisSbMsCtVZnuG6iTiYv',
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
    });
  print(response.statusCode);
  print(response.body);
  return response.body;
}
```

Comment: when i use Uri.https it says (2 positional argument(s) expected, but 1 found.  Try adding the missing arguments.) so, that is the missing arguments?

Comment: I made an edit, try again and see if it works. the first argument is the base url and the second one is the endpoint

Comment: finally i did it by sending a query parameter. thanks for your support!